# How to fix, that TextBox accepts int

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the input type to be int e.g. int number, instead of string and then parsing. So when I try to parse the `InputNumber` `int.Parse(InputNumber.Text)` I get error that Input string was not in a correct format.

It works but whenever I press Backspace to delete the number, my project crashes.

As I said I've tried to parse the Input as int. 
`int.Parse(InputNumber.Text)`

So if I could use int my method would be much shorter and easier to understand.

```
 private void InputNumber_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string number = InputNumber.Text;

            bool isEvenOdd = EvenOddChecker.IsEvenOdd(number);

            OutputNumber.Text = number + (isEvenOdd ? " is a even number" : " is a odd number");

            if (InputNumber.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                OutputNumber.Clear();
            }
        }
```

```
 public static bool IsEvenOdd(string number)
        {
            List<string> even = new List<string>()
            {
                "0","2","4","6","8"
            };
            foreach (var e in even)
            {
                if (number.Substring(0, number.Length - 1).ToString() == e)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I expect the output 2 to be an even number, but the actual output is that's an odd number.

Or e.g. 3 should be an odd number, it says it's even.

Comment: What is value in `number`? is it numberic ?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar 0 , because the user needs to type it.

Comment: use `if(int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out int value)) { }`.

Comment: @SᴇM in method or ?

Comment: There is a typo in your output, it should be "_an_ even number" and "_an_ odd number".

Comment: @IDarkCoder Yup i've had changed it, but the problem was same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply code by using `int.TryParse()`, something like

```
 private void InputNumber_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {

     if(int.TryParse(InputNumber.Text, out int number))
        {
            OutputNumber.Text = number + (number % 2 == 0? " is an even number" : " is an odd number");
                                        //No need to write entire function we have modulo to check even odd  

        }

        if (InputNumber.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            OutputNumber.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have a suggestion for you, you should seperate the if's because it won't clear the output.

Comment: Do you have myb a little time to open a chat, I have 1 question about another program?

Comment: Please go ahead if it is related to same code, if this is from another program then it is better to write one more question, before that read [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I link you the question, i've post it 3 days ago, but there isn't exact answer ?

Comment: Because they will tag it as duplicate.

Comment: @Bob, if moderator is saying it is duplicate then same question might be asked earlier, If you explain it in better way then definitely you will get answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using wrong event IMO. You want to validate the number after it is entered, not WHILE it is entered. Your event you have subscriebed is fired on every change in text in a textbox.

So I'd `if` checking if, for example, enter button was pressed, then I'd allow code to run, but this can be checked in `KeyUp` event, something like this:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

  // your validation
}
```

In that handler you can check and try parse the number, because you are SURE that the number is entered and the user wants that number to be entered by pressing Enter button (after parsing you just need to check if `number % 2` equals to zero).

Also your method `IsEvenOdd` can be simplified to:

```
even.Contains(number);
```

which will return true, if number is in a list, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.TryParse()` to avoid exception:

```
private void InputNumber_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string number = InputNumber.Text;

    if(int.TryParse(number, out int value))
    {
        bool isEven = value % 2 == 0;

        OutputNumber.Text = number + (isEven ? " is an even number" : " is an odd number");

        if (InputNumber.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            OutputNumber.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

and then by doing `yourIntValue % 2 == 0` you can check if your number is even or odd.

Comment: Thanks I have question do you have a bit time to open chat, I have question about another program, since I need to wait 90min to ask again, it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
I used `int.TryParse`to catch all errors of "faulty" inputs.

```
private void InputNumber_TextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    string numberString = InputNumber.Text;

    if (!int.TryParse(numberString, out int number)) 
    {
        OutputNumber.Clear();
        return;
    }

    bool isEven = EvenOddChecker.IsEven(number);

    OutputNumber.Text = number + (isEven ? " is an even number" : " is an odd number");

    if (InputNumber.Text == string.Empty) 
    {
        OutputNumber.Clear();
    }
}
```

To check if the number is even this should be the fastest way:

```
public static bool IsEven (int number) => number % 2 == 0;
```